# Shading areas in coreplot, with outlined line

Tags: ios, core-plot

Does anyone know how to achieve this in coreplot?

[image]

I can get the graph with the solid green and red lines, without the shading.  And I can get the semi-transparent shading, without the solid green and red line.  I cannot seem to get both.  :)

Comment: I did this by creating 4 graphs, 2 that shades the area, and 2 with lines that doesn't shade...same data points.  Cheeky, but it works.  If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with only two plots, one for each color. Set both the `dataLineStyle` and `areaFill` for each plot. Be sure to set the `areaBaseValue` for each plot at or below the bottom of the plot so the fill extends all the way down.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!  I was erroneously setting plot.opacity, which made both the line and the fill transparent.